# Make curl download using non-Privacy extension IPv6 address?

Tags: ipv6, curl

I currently use net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr=2 to get IPv6 privacy addresses (which have a random host part are and regenerated a couple times a day). I need dynamic DNS because the computer is connected to different networks and that changes the network part of the address. I'm using curl to download a dynamic DNS url and want it to use the Non-random address that uses my MAC. How can I make curl prefer the non-privacy address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [ajmitch](https://askubuntu.com/users/129/ajmitch)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/48735/9308) and some scripting to do this. (If anyone has a better way of getting the address, I would be glad to hear it.) You'll need to install [curl](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/curl)

```
#! /bin/sh
# (C) 2011 Erik B. Andersen <erik.b.andersen@gmail.com>
# Licensed under the latest version of the GPL as published by the Free Software Foundation

# Don't bother to reload when lo is configured.
if [ "$IFACE" = lo ]; then
        echo "Interface lo; skipping"
        exit 0
fi

if [ ! -e /usr/bin/curl ]; then
        echo "Curl not installed; skipping"
        exit 0
fi
if [ ! -e /sbin/ifconfig ]; then
        echo "Ifconfig not installed; skipping"
        exit 0
fi
if [ ! -e /bin/grep ]; then
        echo "Grep not installed; skipping"
        exit 0
fi
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/tr ]; then
        echo "Tr not installed; skipping"
        exit 0
fi
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/tail ]; then
        echo "Tail not installed; skipping"
        exit 0
fi

Hostname="something.example.org"
Password="something"
Interface="wlan0"

echo "Running curl"
curl --interface $(/sbin/ifconfig ${Interface} | /bin/grep "Global" | /usr/bin/tr "/" "\n" | /usr/bin/tr " " "\n" | /bin/grep "ff:fe"| /usr/bin/tail -n 1) -6 http://${Hostname}:${Password}@dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=${Hostname}

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can force curl to use a specific source address with the `--interface` option of curl, e.g.

`curl --interface 2001:db8::f00:1234 http://example.com/updatedns.html`

Comment: This could work, but I would have to make some kind of script to determine the address to tell curl to use. I was kind of hoping for a way to say to use the non-privacy address without writing a script to decide which is which.

Comment: There isn't really a way to do that, as an interface can have multiple global addresses, and I don't believe that curl currently allows preferring the public addresses instead of the temporary address except by manually binding to a particular interface/ip address

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer with the script I put together so it's a complete answer to my problem? You could then edit the script if you thought there was a better way to do it.

Comment: @Azendale: you can create a new answer which you accept, but upvote this one because it helped you.